# hibernate - Why do i need to put child into parent collection before saving entites

Tags: java, hibernate

Assume i have these 2 entites

```
@Entity
public class Item {
@Id
protected Long itemId;
protected String title;
protected String description;
protected Date postdate;
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="item")
protected Set<Bid> bids;
...
}
@Entity
public class Bid {
@Id
protected Long bidId;
protected Double amount;
protected Date timestamp;
...
@ManyToOne
protected Item item;
...
}
```

I have seen a lot of tutorial about hibernate but i don't understand why do i need to save child to parent collection like: itemObj.addBid(bidObj). I think the relationship is managed by the Bid so i only need to set the Item reference to Bid object like: bidObj.setItem(itemObj). And when i don't add Bid to Item collection, everything works fine. Do i need to set the reference on both side before saving? And do you know any documentations about how Hibernate scan entites, it's still vague to me how Hibernate scans entities and connect them through their relationship. Thank you.

Comment: You don't **have** to. The correct values will be stored in the database if you don't. But you will end up with an incoherent object graph, where a Bid belongs to an Item, but the item doesn't have the Bid into its bids. And this can of course be the source for bugs.

Comment: @JBNizet Does Hibernate maintains Java Bid and Item object some where. I thought that Bid and Item entities is just a way to map to database. When i don't add Bid to Item collection. I can still fetch every item's bids.

Comment: It maintains it in its first-level cahce, i.e. the session, which typically only lasts until the transaction ends. But in this transaction, if you get the bids from the item, you won't get the correct values.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you i understand it now. Do you have any source about Hibernate, i've read the documentation but it's kinda vague, i want to understand how hibernate works behind the scene, like how the entities is scanned, how Hibernate connects them through defined relationship.

Comment: Except for a few blog posts, I've never read anything other than the documentation. This book is probably very good (https://vladmihalcea.com/books/high-performance-java-persistence/), but I've never read it.

Comment: @JBNizet Can i ask one more thing about mappedBy? I understand the owning-side and inverse-side concept but i still don't understand mappedBy. Is mappedBy only used for telling Hibernate that this entity (entity with mappedBy) and the other side entity is in a relationship, don't make any join table, use the owning-side FK column to join this relationship. And when i do something like, bidObj.setItem(itemObj), does Hibernate get the itemObj's id and put it into the saving query.?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.